# comparing and creating Point 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, double

So i am still trying to get this to work... I need it to tell me with the users position matches the position of one of the walls in the array.

I output all the coordinates into the console and everything looks right except that when they equal it doesn't work.  (this has worked before... it seems if i don't create the walls in the loop it will work but once i declare too many walls it seems to quit working(not exactly sure but i set the map without the loop and it didn't work consistently i couldn't figure out a reason..

The `GameObject(user).position` is `Point2D` and `setPosition set the posiion,

```
public class Map {
    public ArrayList<Wall> theseWalls = new ArrayList<Wall>();
    private boolean isSomethingThere;

    public Boolean somethingIsThere(GameObject user){
        for(int i = 0; i < theseWalls.size(); i++){
            GameObject a = (Wall) theseWalls.get(i); 

            if( user.returnPosition().equals(a.returnPosition())){
                isSomethingThere= true;
            } else {
                isSomethingThere= false;
            }
        }
        return isSomethingThere;
    }
}
```

so that checks if they hit a wall

and this makes the walls

```
public void makeWallWE(double starty, double endy, double x ){
    double length = endy - starty;
    for(int i = 1; i<=(int)length;i++){

        Wall Wallie= new Wall();
        Wallie.setPosition(x,starty+i);

        Wallie.showPosition();

        theseWalls.add(Wallie);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your output look like?

Comment: You can replace point comparison with comparing x and y values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
public Boolean somethingIsThere(GameObject user){
    for(int i = 0; i < theseWalls.size(); i++){
        GameObject a = (Wall) theseWalls.get(i); 

        if( user.returnPosition().equals(a.returnPosition())){
            isSomethingThere= true;
        } else {
            isSomethingThere= false;
        }
    }
    return isSomethingThere;
}
```

Even if the user's position matches one of the walls, you continue checking through the rest of the walls and end up setting `isSomethingThere` to `false`. The only time this works is if the last wall in `theseWalls` is the one that matches.

You'll want to break out of that loop as soon as you find a wall that matches, to avoid resetting `isSomethingThere` to `false` when you check walls later in the list that don't match.

Comment: So if I initialize it to false and remove the else statement I should be good?

Comment: Sure that works too. Breaking out of the loop as soon as it becomes true will save you from continuing the tests after you already know what the result will be, but it's not necessary - it's a common simple performance optimization that I just sort of instinctively do at this point.

Comment: how do you break out of a loop?

Comment: `break`. Read [Control Flow Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). It's short, well-written, and will clear that all up.